# Problem with callback() while using console prompt libraries in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, libraries

Every time I use libraries, no matter what the library is, which are allow me input data into the console, bug that doesn't allow me to use correctly callback function appears. The problem is that callback is working without the data input part, but when I'm using it,it starts after function which is starts after the main function.

```
const {prompt} = require('enquirer');

function second(error) {
    if (!error) console.log('I\'m third') //but in reality second
}

function main(callback) {
    console.log('I\'m first')
    const response = prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'title',
        message: 'Please write title'
    })
    console.log(response); //must be second but in reality third
    callback()
}

main(second);
```

Here is console output:

```
I'm first
Promise { <pending> }
I'm third
✔ Please write title · 1
```

I think it is my fault, because I`m novice in callbacks and in Node.js in general.
I would be really happy if you could help me.

Comment: `console.log(response);` does print the `Promise { <pending> }`, no?

Comment: You'll need to wait for the `response` promise, using either `.then()` or `await` syntax. Surely the docs of the *enquirer* library have examples

Comment: Yes it does, where is an option in the description of libriary to skip this log but I copypasted just regular version, here is the libraries npm site https://www.npmjs.com/package/enquirer

Comment: Thanks I will try it soon

Comment: Put `async` in front of `function main`, and put `async` between the `=` and `prompt`. Just like the first example in the enquirer docs.

Comment: And to help you understand, `prompt` is an _asynchronous_ function. When you call it, it sets up the prompt and then returns immediately, before the user responds. So you need to either use `async`/`await` or use the `then` method with a callback on the `Promise` that `prompt` returns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand how this stuff works

Answer (score 0):

```
const {prompt} = require('enquirer');

function second(error) {
    if (!error) console.log('I\'m third') 
}

async function main(callback) {
    console.log('I\'m first')
    const response = await prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'title',
        message: 'Please write title'
    })
    console.log(response); 
    callback()
}

main(second);
```